# How do I ignore numbers at the end of a line to compare a string?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have lines that get tested every time I run a my file they are not always the same lines. What I want to do is test them against another line to check if they are the same. The question says partially because at the end of every line there are numbers that I don't want to take into account when making the comparison.

In the snippet below I tried to add another function that compares every line against the lines that I know will come out so that if it finds it, it returns a query that I need to run onto the screen

```
error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0
warning: incorrect info 1.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/myfiles' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/css' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/js' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 5615612.0
```

This is what I tried to do but I don't know how to ignore the numbers so that the lines could actually compare. **All of this happens after the first section is ran where I get the numbers that are grater than 0.0**.

Meaning this lines get compared.

```
error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0
warning: incorrect info 1.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 5615612.0

if ("error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0" == line){
    //run this query for database runtimeDB
}
if("warning: incorrect info 1.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for incorrectInfoDB
}
if("warning: file at 'C://localhost/myfiles' not found 0.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for incorrectInfoDB
}
if("warning: file at 'C://localhost/css' not found 0.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for outerfilesDB
}
if("warning: file at 'C://localhost/css' not found 0.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for outerfilesDB
}
if("warning: file at 'C://localhost/js' not found 0.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for outerfilesDB
}
if("warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 0.0" == line){
    //this query
    //+1 for outerfilesDB
}
```

this is the actual code that I tried. There is code reused that can be optimized. At the end everything gets saved in an array and all arrays get printed out depending on their databases the queries query on.

```
function compare_RT(){
    var text = $('textarea').val();
    var lines = text.split("\n");
    var runtimeDB= [];
    lines.forEach(function(line){

        var string0 = "error: there were errors found during runtime"

        if(line.includes(string0)){
            runtimeDB.push(line);
        }
    });
return runtimeDB;
}
function compare_IInfo(){
    var text = $('textarea').val();
    var lines = text.split("\n");
    var incorrectInfoDB= [];
    lines.forEach(function(line){

        var string0 = "error: there were errors found during runtime"
        var string1 = "warning: file at 'C://localhost/myfiles' not found"

        if(line.includes(string0)){
            incorrectInfoDB.push(line);
        }
        if(line.includes(string1)){
            incorrectInfoDB.push(line);
        }
    });
return incorrectInfoDB;
}
```

```js
function getLines() {
  var text = $('textarea').val();
  var lines = text.split("\n");
  var requiredLines = [];
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    number = line.match(/\d+\.\d+$/);
    if (number != null && number[0] > 0)
      requiredLines.push(line);
  });
  return requiredLines;
}


$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('#printlogs').html(getLines().join('<br>'));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="width:100%;height:120px">
error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0
warning: incorrect info 1.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/myfiles' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/css' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/js' not found 0.0
warning: file at 'C://localhost/assets' not found 5615612.0
</textarea>

<h4>Error Log</h4>
<printlogs id="printlogs"></printlogs>
```

Comment: So if I understand correct, all you have to check is if the message is same and ignore line numbers. Correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: I don't understand where the error is, you already use `.include()` to check that, you can also use `.contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can adapt it to your solution.

```
function trim_numbers($string) {
    //Get the numbers after the last whitespace.
    //strrchr — Find the last occurrence of a character in a string.
    $numbers = strrchr($string, ' ');

    //Replace found numbers with nothing ('').
    //$numbers is now equal to ' 12.0'.
    return str_replace($numbers, '', $string);
}

echo trim_numbers("error: there were errors found during runtime 12.0");
```

Output:

> error: there were errors found during runtime

[Working snippet](https://ideone.com/V03PAj)